i intall openairinterface with document installation in http://onnocenter.or.id/wiki/index.php/4G:_OpenAirInterface_dari_OpenCell
i intall openairinterface with document installation in http://onnocenter.or.id/wiki/index.php/4G:_OpenAirInterface_dari_OpenCell
at the source code
Install 3PP SW untuk mme dan spgw:
sudo apt fix-broken install
cd ~/openair-cn
source oaienv
cd scripts
./build_mme -i
i've stuck on eror:
mme compilation failed
cp: cannot stat '/home/aye/openair-cn/build/mme/build/mme': No such file or directory
auth_request compilation failed
cp: cannot stat '/home/aye/openair-cn/build/mme/build/auth_request': No such file or directory
how can i fix it? help please
i try to fix with searching the solution, but i can't find it, help me for solution
